# Prolog - Add a special character to every element of a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to add a special character (*) to every element of a list.

I want to add it in the beginning and the end of the element, so if I have:

```
list(apple,orange,pear)
```

It would be:

```
list(*apple*,*orange*,*pear*)
```

Is there a way to do that in prolog?

Thank you.

Comment: Use maplist/3   (Added text to make comment limit happy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To concatenate two atoms, you can use the ISO predicate [atom_concat/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_concat/3):

```
?- atom_concat('*', apple, StarAtom), atom_concat(StarAtom, '*', StarAtomStar).
StarAtom = '*apple',
StarAtomStar = '*apple*'.
```

Using this predicate, you can define the following new predicate:

```
% starry_atom(+Atom, -StarAtomStar)

  starry_atom(Atom, StarAtomStar) :-
      atom_concat('*', Atom, StarAtom),
      atom_concat(StarAtom, '*', StarAtomStar).
```

Example:

```
?- starry_atom(apple, StarryAtom).
StarryAtom = '*apple*'.
```

To apply `starry_atom/2` to all elements of a list, supposing that all elements of the list are atoms, you can use the predicate [maplist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2).

```
?- maplist(starry_atom, [apple, orange, pear], List).
List = ['*apple*', '*orange*', '*pear*'].
```

**NOTE** In SWI-Prolog, you can also use the predicate [atomic_list_concat/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/2).

```
?- atomic_list_concat(['*', apple, '*'], Atom).
Atom = '*apple*'.
```